# What is the callee token, actual argc and descriptor (on the stack)?

Tags: spidermonkey, stack-frame

Often see the picture of stack like this (it can be another forms but the essence is like):

`... 
args 
... 
thisv 
actual argc 
callee token
descriptor 
return address`

What is the callee token, descriptor and actual argc?

Comment: I don't think I ever seen "callee token" anywhere, google seems a bit confused too. In what context are you seeing these frames? (Language and platform.)

Comment: It's js frame (spidermonkey jit compiler). Yes google often confused about questions like this :( Maybe you know what is actual argc or descriptor?